# getKeyStroke(char) vs. getKeyStroke(char, int) - I don't understand the difference

Tags: java, parameters, keystroke

This code always returns 0:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(someString.charAt(0)).getKeyCode();
```

While this one returns the actual key code:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(someString.charAt(0), 0).getKeyCode();
```

However, I don't understand what the second parameter in getKeyStroke() is good for. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html) does not explain anything except for this parameter is called "modifier" and it doesn't seem to affect the key code in any way, independent from which number I put there.

I'd be glad for an explanation.

Comment: Get a look at the source code, you need to use bitwise constants : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/KeyStroke.java#KeyStroke.getKeyStroke%28java.lang.Character%2Cint%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between keyPressed, keyTyped and keyReleased events.

In the first case a `keyTyped` event is generated. In the second case a `keyPressed` event is generated.

You then need to check out the `KeyEvent` API where you will find:

*For key pressed and key released events, the getKeyCode method returns the event's keyCode. For key typed events, the getKeyCode method always returns VK_UNDEFINED.*

Edit:

Actually the above answer is not complete enough. Check out the following demo code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStroke ks1 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( 'a' );
        System.out.println( ks1 );
        KeyStroke ks2 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a', 0);
        System.out.println( ks2 );
    }
}
```

And I get the following output:

```
typed a
pressed NUMPAD1
```

From the `getKeyStroke(Character keyChar, int modifiers)` API:

*Note that the first parameter is of type Character rather than char. This is to avoid inadvertent clashes with calls to getKeyStroke(int keyCode, int modifiers).*

So, I would say the modifier has nothing to do with the problem. The problem is the 'a' is being treated as an int and is mapped to a different KeyStroke than you expect.

Trying to generate character using the Robot is always risky. Here is a simple example you might be able to use:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RobotCharacter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( textField );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );

        Robot robot = new Robot();
        typeCharacter(robot, "a");
        typeCharacter(robot, "b");
        typeCharacter(robot, "C");
        typeCharacter(robot, "D");
     }

    public static void typeCharacter(Robot robot, String letter)
    {
        try
        {
            boolean upperCase =  
                    Character.isUpperCase(letter.charAt(0) );
            String variableName = "VK_" + letter.toUpperCase();

            Class clazz = KeyEvent.class;
            Field field = clazz.getField( variableName );
            int keyCode = field.getInt(null);

            robot.delay(1000);

            if (upperCase)
            {
                robot.keyPress( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );
            }
            robot.keyPress( keyCode );
            robot.keyRelease( keyCode );

            if (upperCase)
            {
                robot.keyRelease( KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Works fine with letters/numbers, but you will always have problems with special characters ($, %, &...). I would suggest you look for a different approach instead of using a Robot.

You can try creating a Hashmap of characters and its corresponding KeyEvent.VK_???. Even this approach has problems because some characters need the shift key and some keyboards are different so some may need a shift key and others may not.

Comment: Thanks, that makes some sense to me. But that brings up a followup question: _"a set of modifiers, specifying whether the key is activated when it is pressed or released"_ - this however does not make sense to me, because I only used this with the **java.awt.Robot** class so far. So I don't understand what _"whether the key is activated"_ means. What I understand is, if I invoke **Robot.keyPress(keyCode)**, a key stroke is simulated.

Comment: Oh, I've never tested it with shifted special characters... But I'm doing the same thing as you do with your "upperCase" check which is why I still don't get the use of the modifiers for this scenario. But I've learned something from the answers today. And thank you for taking the time for this "standalone" example and for explaining that much!

Comment: `I still don't get the use of the modifiers for this scenario.` - The value is 0, so  you  are not using modifiers. The modifier has no meaning for the key code.

Answer (score 2):

The modifiers are bitwise masks for simultaniously pressing e.g. the ctrl button or the shift button. Don't just put any number in there.

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('a', java.awt.event.InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK | java.awt.event.InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK);
```

would be the correct usage of the modifier if the ctrl or the shift button should be pressed with 'a'

Comment: OK, I see the difference in the console. But when it comes to simulating key strokes, the modifiers don't matter, do they? Because **java.awt.Robot.keyPress()** only takes keyCodes (int) and as explained in the OP, the modifiers don't (seem to) affect the key code.